# Generalized Hypergeometric reduction formula

Tags: hypergeometric-function, reduction-formula

The Wikipedia piece on generalized hypergeometric functions lists a reduction formula that looks suspicious to me. Just over Euler's integral transform ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Basic_properties)):

$$
{}_{A+1}F_{B+1}\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1},\ldots ,a_{A},c + n \\ 
b_{1},\ldots ,b_{B},c
\end{array}
;z\right] = \sum_{j = 0}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{1}{(c)_j} \frac{\prod_{i = 1}^A (a_i)_j}{\prod_{i = 1}^B (b_i)_j} {}_AF_B\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1} + j,\ldots ,a_{A} + j \\ 
b_{1} + j,\ldots ,b_{B} + j
\end{array}
;z\right]
$$

Applying this rule to $(z+1)\exp(z) = {}_1 F_1(2;1;z)$ I get $2\exp(z)$.

There is a reference for the formula to a 1990 Collection that doesn't seem to be available online.

Could anyone (a) confirm that the equation is faulty in its current version on Wikipedia and (b) supply a correct Version?

Comment: Elliot is right, in fact, you can prove it using https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.3 and beating 16.3.1 and 16.3.2 together:)   (I am pretty sure :) )

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the expression on the Wikipedia page has an error. As your example suggests, the right hand side is missing some factors of $z$. A more general version of the order reduction formula [can be found here](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1665587). Using the special case of that formula where we reduce the order only by $1$, the correct version of the Wikipedia formula should be
$$
{}_{A+1}F_{B+1}\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1},\ldots ,a_{A},c + n \\ 
b_{1},\ldots ,b_{B},c
\end{array}
;z\right] = \sum_{j = 0}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{1}{(c)_j} \frac{\prod_{i = 1}^A (a_i)_j}{\prod_{i = 1}^B (b_i)_j} \color{red}{z^j} {}_AF_B\left[ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_{1} + j,\ldots ,a_{A} + j \\ 
b_{1} + j,\ldots ,b_{B} + j
\end{array}
;z\right]
$$